# Modify link options when hovering over post title

Tags: title

In dashboard, clicking on "Posts" reveals rows of posts. When I hover over one of them, specifically over their title, I get hyperlink options such as "Edit" and "Trash". I have a plugin that adds another hyperlink option "Duplicate", however I'd prefer to get rid of this option (depending on the post type). I've checked the plugin settings but there are no options there that will allow me to do this. Is there way to change the hyperlink options when hovering over the posts' titles?

Comment: Do you just want to get rid of the link because it is annoying or you want to remove the link injection for some technical issues?

Comment: I do not know the specific hook, but this should be around [manage_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column).

Comment: I want to remove the link because it doesn't work correctly for a certain custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just hide the link in the admin area, you can add this CSS code to your admin area. Assuming that the extra link is the LAST one in the row, add this code to you theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');
function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>.row-actions span:last-child {display:none} </style>';
```

This will hide the link added by the plug-in. If the extra link is not the last one in the row, then you have to replace `:last-child` with `:nth-child(n)`, which `(n)` is the number of the element in the row, starting from 1.

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing it in CSS because I thought it would be applied late in the program flow, which might make the link appear temporarily before it suddenly disappears. However, putting the CSS in the functions.php worked very well.